# Number of solutions to $a+b+c+d=S$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How to  find number of solutions to $a+b+c+d = S$, where $a,b,c,d\in\{2,\ldots, S\}.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have a question?

Comment: It's $\binom{S-5}{3}$ by stars and bars.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling can you explain how did you arrive at this solution. Thanks for replying.

Comment: google stars and bars method, I have answered this question at least 30 times before.

Comment: to reach the theorem 1 case, you need to pre include 1 star in each from a,b,c,d since they must be > 1. Using the stars and bars models requires to ignore the commutativity of +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = x+2, b = y+2, c = z+2, d = t+2 \implies x+y+z+t = S-8$ with $x,y,z,t \ge 0$. Thus you count the number of non-negative integer solutions of the above equation. The formula is: $\binom{(S-8)+ 4-1}{4-1} = \binom{S-5}{3}$. Note that $4$ is the number of variables, and $S-8$ is number on the right side of the equation.